# What is wrong with my call to checkodesol in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I am learning `sympy`, and wanted to verify the solution to an ODE. I do not yet quite understand sympy naming conventions.

Instead of doing the standard methods of loading all packages at the top, I wanted to just `import sympy` and then use explicit long name to reference any other name inside sympy.  On latest conda python

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
```

When typing

```
import sympy
x   = sympy.symbols('x')
y   = sympy.Function('y')
ode = sympy.Eq(sympy.Derivative(y(x),x),1+2*x)
sol = sympy.dsolve(ode,y(x))
sympy.solvers.ode.checkodesol(ode,sol)
```

And the above gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'sympy.solvers.solvers' has no attribute 'ode'
```

But from the page https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/ode.html

It says

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But if I do the following, it works

```
from sympy import checkodesol
checkodesol(ode,sol)
    (True, 0)
```

But I do not want to import `checkodesol` explicitly. I want to just import `sympy` and then use the long name to call `checkodesol` or any other sympy sub packages, as this makes it more clear to me in the code where each function is coming from (at the cost of a little extra typing)

The question is, why using `sympy.solvers.ode.checkodesol` does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very top of the documentation you linked to, it says

> These are functions that are imported into the global namespace with
>   `from sympy import *`. These functions (unlike Hint Functions, below)
>   are intended for use by ordinary users of SymPy.

Then you can use `checkodesol(ode, sol)` directly.

If you do `import sympy`, then you need to call

```
sympy.checkodesol(ode, sol)
```